# Did Old English have a similar adverb phrase or interjection like "of course"?

Tags: etymology, old-english

I'm writing a story that heavily uses archaic or unusual English words, with a focus of non-Latin, non-French and non-Anglo-Norman derived words and how English might work without them.

I found very little that makes sense to use in place of that phrase, 'of course' as we use it now. According to Wiktionary "course" has been around since Middle English. The entry for 'of course' makes note of a meaning going back to the 16th century.

So I'm guessing maybe they would have used something utterly different before then. Any clues as to what?

The part of speech I'm looking for, is as an adverb or interjection, such as:

"Did you get the jam?", he asked. "Of course", I answered.

"Of course I know the answer!", she growled.

Comment: You can play around with the [Old English translator](https://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk) to try and find something suitable, but you need to start with single words. I found these possibilities: afæstla, eallunga (both translate as 'assuredly'); witodlice (= "certainly").

Comment: Gaston Ümlaut: afæstla led to a wonderful paper on OE emotional interjections: [How the Anglo-Saxons Expressed Their Emotions with the Help of Interjections](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/105146/1_BrnoStudiesEnglish_35-2009-2_14.pdf?sequence=1). For that alone you have my thanks. And, 'Assuredly' seems a likely substitute for 'of course'.

Comment: [*Gewis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gewiss), perhaps?